# How to replace a variable and then execute the command

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to create a shell script which retrieves values of all JIRA issues and stores it in a file. Here i want to be able to interpret the value of a variable before executing it.

I have tried several alternatives and have exhausted all my options. I have used single quotes, double quotes even escape characters for dollar sign. even the exec command but none of them works

```
var1="project in (ELIP)"

./jira.sh --action getIssueList --jql "$var1"  --columns "Key" --outputFormat 999  --file "/root/scripts/getList.txt"
```

Note: The command ./jira.sh expects the --jql parameter to be in double quotes.

What i expect is that the value of `$var1` should be interpreted first and then the `./jira.sh` command should run. But I cannot get it to work.

Comment: *Why* does `jira.sh` expect the argument to `--jql` to contain quotes? And what do you mean by "interpret"?

Comment: This looks okay. If you need double quotes, you need to escape them, e.g. `"\"$var1\""`.

Comment: I posted an answer. If you want more detail please indicate which shell you are running (sh, bash, ksh), which version of it and what does `jira.sh` do

Comment: Thanks Brunorey. If I run it with an exec command it works but without exec it does not.                                                                exec ./jira.sh --action getIssueList --jql "$var1"  --columns "Key" --outputFormat 999  --file "/root/scripts/updateFieldEllipse/getList.txt"  ---WORKS                                                                                                                      but  ./jira.sh --action getIssueList --jql "$var1"  --columns "Key" --outputFormat 999  --file "/root/scripts/updateFieldEllipse/getList.txt" DOES NOT WORK

Comment: I'm happy you got it to work. Your comment is not 100% clear, if you want a better answer please edit your question adding exactly what works and what doesn't.

Comment: When you run `exec` you are running it in a different environment from your shell. `exec` sets up it's own shell instance and doesn't inherit most of your configuration and variables, hence it may behave differently. If you consider my answer to be correct please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know exactly what jira.sh does, but here's some explanation on shell variables (tested with bash, other shells may behave differently):

Firstly use a test script to inform how parameters are received:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo arg1: $1
echo arg2: $2
echo arg3: $3
```

Now if we run with literal text arguments (no variables)

```
$ ./test.sh arg_no_1 'multiple words argument' arg_no_3
arg1: arg_no_1
arg2: multiple words argument
arg3: arg_no_3
```

Now we define our variable (with single quotes)

```
$ variable='multiple words variable'
```

If you run without quotes you get a wrong output, variable gets expanded in bash and takes the slots of the next arguments:

```
$ ./test.sh arg_no_1 $variable arg_no_3
arg1: arg_no_1
arg2: multiple
arg3: words
```

If we try wrapping it in simple quotes, the variable won't be interpreted and instead sent to the script as a literal.

```
$ ./test.sh arg_no_1 '$variable' arg_no_3
arg1: arg_no_1
arg2: $variable
arg3: arg_no_3
```

But wrapping in double quotes yields the expected result:

```
$ ./test.sh arg_no_1 "$variable" arg_no_3
arg1: arg_no_1
arg2: multiple words variable
arg3: arg_no_3
```

You should read up on quote usage. A short explanation: in shell single quotes `'` are treated as literal content and the variables within them are not interpreted. Double quotes `"` are taken as content to be interpreted and variables inside them are replaced with their value. Here's some info on [tldp](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html) regarding quotes. Also, [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) has info.